# Rails Capistrano fails on assets:precompile SSHKIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, ssh, capistrano

When I deploy my application to Digital Ocean (Ubuntu 18.04). The deployment process fails deploy:assets:precompile. It doesn't provide a specific error. I browsed numerous similar cases, but they don't solve the problem.

I checked my ssh settings and they seem to be correct. The #AllowAgentForwarding setting in ssh_config is set to yes (both local and remote).  ssh-add -l alsi returns the correct ssh agent

Any thoughts? Thanks for the help!

Below is my error output:

```
00:09 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 I, [2019-07-11T10:37:53.282876 #17762]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 2.9.0 ready to catch errors
      01 yarn install v1.16.0
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 [2/4] Fetching packages...
      01 info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
      01 info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
      01 info fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
      01 info "fsevents@2.0.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
      01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
      01 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
      01 Done in 22.00s.
      01 Compiling…
      01 Compilation failed:
      01
      01
#<Thread:0x00007fbb8d3ba470@/Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    12: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    11: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
    10: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:92:in `within'
     8: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:68:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:100:in `with'
     6: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:69:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
     4: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
     3: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
     2: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
     1: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:169:in `execute_command'
/Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
rake stdout: I, [2019-07-11T10:37:53.282876 #17762]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 2.9.0 ready to catch errors
yarn install v1.16.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.0.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 22.00s.
Compiling…
Compilation failed:
rake stderr: Nothing written
    1: from /Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/sebastiaan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.19.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@134.209.201.210: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
rake stdout: I, [2019-07-11T11:12:13.618508 #20267]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 2.9.0 ready to catch errors
yarn install v1.16.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.0.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 22.95s.
Compiling…
Compilation failed:
rake stderr: Nothing written
```

Capfile:

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
require "capistrano/rbenv"
require "capistrano/rails"
require "capistrano/passenger"
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.3'
```

The

Deploy.rb

```
lock "~> 3.11.0"
set :application, "youba"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:pspoppen/youba.git"
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}"
append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml'
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'
set :keep_releases, 10
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }
```

Gemfile (related gems)

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.x'
```

Answer (score 1):

SSH is not your problem. From the log you provided, an error happens during assets compilation.

I'd recommend logging in to the server, cloning the project to a temp directory, and running `rails assets:precompile` manually. This would probably fail, and you'd have to find out why.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried to precompile in a cloned temp folder and it compiles all the assets without failure. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You would have to find out what's the difference between Capistrano environment and your temp test environment. Different Linux user? Different PATH or other ENV variables? Different Rails environment (`development` / `production`) Different directory structure? Things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some swap to your VM and you should be fine. During assets compilation looks like it runs out of RAM and fails. IT happens if you have a small VM with 1GB of RAM. To verify that.. install htop (`apt-get install htop`) utility on your VM and open in during your deployment. You should see stats then. I have had the same problem. My solution was to compile on local pc and copy over them (you can make a task for that in Capistrano)

Answer (score 1):

@Nordic Panda and @Claasz, Thankyou for your help! The insufficient amount of memory was indeed the problem and caused the compilation to fail. I resized my Digital Ocean account and double now the deploy works fine!

Before I did this (and still with the lighter server). I compiled the assets locally and deployed them separately as you suggested. This also worked fine!